# Debugging deployed dylib in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, dylib

> Here's the setup:

Assume I have Xcode project `Foo` with one scheme `Foo` producing `libFoo.dylib`. This whole project is located in `~/projects/Foo`. After build (cmd+b), dylib is saved in `~/projects/Foo/obj/Debug/libFoo.dylib`.

My project consists of multiple libraries and the actual executable is `.jar` file. Let's assume this project is located in `~/app/`. `libFoo` depends on multiple libraries, which are all stored in `~/app/` folder. Executable is stored in `~/app/Bar.jar`.

The task is to build `libFoo`, copy it into deployment directory (`~/app/`), run executable and debug `libFoo` inside Xcode.

> What worked for me and for no apparent reason stopped working:

I've set up *Pre-action* for *Run* in my scheme, which is a simple applescript copying library into deployment directory.

Executable to debug is **java**, arguments passed on launch is something like `-jar Bar.jar`. Working directory is set to custom: `~/app/`.

> What's working

Upon running (cmd+r): project is built, library is copied into deployment directory, jarfile is executed and debugging inside Xcode starts up.

> What's the actual issue

For some reason, the library debugged in Xcode is not the one deployed in `~/app/`, but the one in `Debug` directory. This produces an error on unresolved reference for dependant library, which obviously is only present in `app` directory.

The actual error is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ~/app/libFoo.dylib:
dlopen(~/app/libFoo.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @loader_path/dependent_library.dylib
Referenced from: ~/projects/Foo/obj/Debug/libFoo.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

All our libraries have their names set to `@loader_path/lib.dylib` and references to dependent libraries are also in this format.